# Ruby floating point addition error

Tags: ruby

I am using ruby 2.3.0p0.

I have been trying to do a simple addition using 2 float numbers in ruby

```
irb(main):001:0> 1.50 + 14.99
=> 16.490000000000002
```

The desired result should be `16.49` instead of `16.490000000000002`

```
a = 1.5
b = 14.99
c = a + b
```

How could I fixed this so that I could get `16.49` for variable c

Cheers.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Well I guess I have solve it in a way that might not be that elegant. require 'bigdecimal'; (BigDecimal('1.5') + BigDecimal('14.99')).to_f. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Since floating point numbers are not as precise as you think they are, they often include tiny bits of noise that result from various calculations, it's your responsibility to specify what level of precision you want when displaying them:

```
a = 1.5
b = 14.99

c = a + b

puts '%.2f' % c
```

The `%.2f` notation here means to have two places. `%.9f` would be nine places.

This is how floating point numbers work. Don't expect them to be neat and tidy.